# Failure to transfer org.apache.maven: maven-artifact-manager:pom:2.0.6 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

Tags: java, spring, apache, maven, configuration

I had some problems at the time of import a spring mvc project, i already did and resolved a lot of dependency issues. Currently i just have the following error:

Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:pom:2.0.6 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connection timed out to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact-manager/2.0.6/maven-artifact-manager-2.0.6.pom pom.xml

I thought it was a network problem but it does not. Any suggestions ??? (I repeat: I don't have dependency issues)

Comment: If you're getting a timeout trying to connect to repo.maven.apache.org, how is it not a network problem?

Comment: I already tried to connect to that address and at least in the browser it does not have any problems, moreover my issue ws presented since 3 days. It is not a network problem.

Comment: If it works with your browser bot not from command line i assume you have proxy in between so you need to check the settings.xml file or your network connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally resolved the problem, it was such a kind of cleaning, here are the steps

-Right click on project Run as/maven clean

-Right click on project Run as/maven install

-Right click on project Maven/Update project and check the option: Force update of snapshots/releases

-Restart STS or Eclipse IDE